# How could HMAC comparison ever not be constant-time in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, security, hmac, timing-attack

Python has a method specifically for comparing HMAC to prevent timing attacks: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hmac.html#hmac.compare_digest

And I read about timing attacks here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74547/timing-attack-against-hmac-in-authenticated-encryption

My question is, how could it possibly ever not be constant-time? It would be necessary to calculate the actual HMAC in order to compare it, and it's not like you could calculate the digest 1 character at a time, right? At the end, it would just be a simple string comparison, which is 2 orders of magnitude faster than the actual HMAC calculation in my tests. So where exactly is the attack surface here? Could someone please give an example of exactly where the actual vulnerability is if I don't use `hmac.compare_digest()`?

Comment: Because the Python `==` equality test makes no guarantees about it being constant time.

Comment: So basically, you are admitting that it is a purely technical-correctness thing, and it's not actually a practical concern... That's pretty much what I thought it was.

Comment: Uhm, no, I am not. I'm telling you that using `==` opens you up to oracle timing attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the end, it would just be a simple string comparison, which is 2 orders of magnitude faster than the actual HMAC calculation in my tests.

But it is *not constant time*. Just because they are done fast doesn't mean the difference is not measurable. For `bytes` values, Python first tests for equal length and equal first bytes before using [`memcmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) to test the rest.  For strings, Python compares length, then *kind* (if the string uses 1, 2 or 4 bytes per character), then also uses `memcmp`.

The Linux manpage for `memcmp` explicitly states:

> Do not use `memcmp()` to compare security critical data, such as
>          cryptographic secrets, because the required CPU time depends on the
>          number of equal bytes.  Instead, a function that performs comparisons
>          in constant time is required.  Some operating systems provide such a
>          function (e.g., NetBSD's `consttime_memequal()`), but no such function
>          is specified in POSIX.  On Linux, it may be necessary to implement
>          such a function oneself.)

A sufficiently determined attacker can exploit this weakness to figure out what hash you have stored vs the hash of the data it is sending.

Timing attacks make it possible to *forge signatures*. Say, a service stores authorization information in a token shared with the client. If the client could alter this token, they could gain access they would not otherwise have. To protect against this, the token is signed using an HMAC signature, letting the server verify the returned token before accepting it as valid. If the authorization data doesn't match the signature, the token is rejected.

If the server does this:

```
auth_data, signature = split_token(token)
expected = hmac_signature(auth_data)
if signature == expected:
    # ...
```

then an attacker can detect how many characters of a forged signature match the expected signature, and adjust accordingly. They start with `XXXXX:000000...`, then try `XXXXX:1000000...`, etc. until the time taken by the service increases, indicating that they have a matching first character. Then the second character can be altered, until the full signature matches.

Comment: Isn't this all completely pointless if the attacker already has the digest? They could just do it on their own computer.

Comment: @dvtan: no, the attacker does not have the digest, it is trying to figure out how to create new hashes.

Comment: @dvtan: you linked to an article that explains exactly that, that the attacker doesn't have the digest, and doesn't want the digest, it wants to know how to generate a *new* digest for data they control.

Comment: oh right, I was thinking about brute force attacks on the secret key... my mistake it_hurt_itself_in_confusion.jpeg

Comment: I still think that this is just too theoretical, and the random variances would completely swamp out any timing differences in actual practice

Comment: @dvtan: don't underestimate the power of repeated attempts and gathering statistics.